# Which are the simplest way to do cross database references in pgAdmin?

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to do horizontal fragmentation on a table say table employee(attributes) which is in 'Employee' database on 'server1' and such fragments are need to store in table on other databases on same server. For doing this I am currently using rules so that changes can be replicated. For example if some insert happens on one of the fragment then those inserted values should also must get stored on main table. So I need to write cross database referencing queries for this. Can anyone tell me how to write such queries in pgAdmin , specially for creating rules for ex:

```
CREATE RULE  employee1 AS
ON INSERT TO employee WHERE
    (  dno BETWEEN 1 AND 10 )
DO INSTEAD
    INSERT INTO employee1 VALUES ( NEW.eno, NEW.ename, NEW.title, NEW.dno );
```

where table employee and employee1 resides on different database but on same server.

Comment: Putting both "parts" of a single table into two different databases on the *same* server does not make any sense. It will not improve performance nor will it help in scaling. What is the **real** problem you are trying solve here? Why don't just put everything into a single table? And btw: Postgres does not support "cross-database" queries. There are some workarounds using dblink or FDW but I'm pretty sure those will _not_ scale at all.

Comment: Its part of my collage assignment. I just want to test it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had tried both dblink and FDW. I have created foreign server and table using FDW but while creation rule its showing me error:  "employee" is not a table or view ... why

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support cross-database references. Frankly I think this is a terrible idea. Why do you want to do it? It'd be *maybe* useful if you're spreading it across separate servers, but multiple DBs in the same server makes IMO no sense at all.

Comment: I need ans to question rather than arguments